# Why is my program leaking memory allocated for objects I don't use, from a framework I don't use?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory-leaks

I ran a `leaks` report on a program I am developing, with the following results:

```
Process 2454: 155054 nodes malloced for 7464 KB
Process 2454: 6 leaks for 608 total leaked bytes.
Leak: 0x14984360  size=160  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x127000    instance of 'SecCertificate', type CFType, implemented in Security  
    0xa024562c 0x01015580 0x00000000 0xa0575c68     ,V$..U......h\W.
    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000     ................
    0x0046d8cc 0x1492a480 0x00000000 0x4d555458     ..F.........XTUM
    0x00000000 0x00000068 0x00000000 0x00000000     ....h...........
    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000     ................
    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000     ................
    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000     ................
    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000     ................
    ...
Leak: 0x1447cab0  size=144  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x127000    string 'Ä'
Leak: 0x146b4010  size=96  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x127000 instance of 'SecKeychainItem', type CFType, implemented in Security 
    0xa024562c 0x01015980 0x00000000 0xa0575de8     ,V$..Y.......]W.
    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000     ................
    0x0046d8cc 0x1481dbb0 0x00000000 0x4d555458     ..F.........XTUM
    0x00000000 0x00000068 0x00000000 0x00000000     ....h...........
    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000     ................
    0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000 0x00000000     ................
Leak: 0x147ecf70  size=80  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x127000 string 'Ä'
Leak: 0x1481dbb0  size=64  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x127000 string 'O'
Leak: 0x1492a480  size=64  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x127000 string 'ê'
```

The thing is, I'm not even linking to the Security framework, nor am I using any data types of `SecCertificate` or `SecKeychainItem` (or any that reference those data types, to my knowledge). I'm not using the Keychain at all. I never saw this leak from my program during testing before; it just cropped up today. Why would leaks report such a memory leak?

Comment: Are you using any SIMBL plug-ins or input manager/former input manager hacks? SIMBL (at the very least) gets loaded into every process, so even if *you're* not linking to Security, one of these plug-ins/hacks might be. Also, does your application access the web?

Comment: No, no SIMBL in use. The program does use `-[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might likely be a false positive.   If it is only 608 bytes leaked ever, don't worry about it.

Feel free to file a bug via http://bugreport.apple.com/, though.